# Mostrar o erro no campo ao invés de um flash/notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma aplicação Rails com Twitter Bootstrap que, ao criar um registro e apresentar erros, mostra o erro em um flash/notice conforme imagem:[image: imagem]

Porém, gostaria que aparecesse os erros nos campos, e alterasse a classe dos inputs para .has-error ou algo do tipo. Dei uma olhada no field_error_proc e tentei alterá-lo de diversas maneiras, porém, sem sucesso (na verdade, talvez eu tenha feito algo de errado).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando os `form helpers`

```
<%= form_for @post |f| %>
  <% @post.errors[:title].join(", ") %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

os campos com erro tem um output assim:

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
 <input id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="30" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

usando a class `field_with_errors`:

```
.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}
```

[fonte](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors)

Comment: Engraçado que no meu caso os campos não ficam com esta classe "field_with_erros", não sei se é por causa do bootstrap, do simple_form ou alguma outra coisa. Porém, a parte dos erros acima do input deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

No caso do Bootstrap, é possível tornar a borda dos campos com erro vermelha com uma simples linha em jQuery:

```
$(".form-group:has(.field_with_errors)").addClass("has-error");
```

Comment: Ótimo. Isso pode ajudar no caso de eu não conseguir fazer isso automaticamente via CSS juntando com os erros do Rails (pois parece-me que o normal seria o div do input mudar sua classe ao apresentar erros).